# I have received 205 reputation points today

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-cap

I check my reputation received today. It says I have received 205 points. I thought the cap was at 200 per day. Will it go back down to the cap sometime later or is this intended?

Comment: Congratulation!

Comment: You also get a Mortarboard badge when you do that for the first time - congratulations on your new badge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reputation is capped at 200 points from **votes**.

If you have an answer accepted, you accept an answer or you are awarded a bounty these points are immune from the cap and can take your daily reputation over 200.