# Does the bonus rep for associating accounts across different SE sites go against daily rep cap?

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-cap

Does the +100 bonus rep for associating accounts across different Stack Exchange sites go against the +200 daily rep count?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, it's as @ChrisF [mentioned](https://meta.superuser.com/q/1730/4377).

> Reputation is capped at 200 points
>   from votes.
>
> If you have an answer accepted, you
>   accept an answer or you are awarded a
>   bounty these points are immune from
>   the cap and can take your daily
>   reputation over 200.

You can [audit your rep](https://superuser.com/reputation) , FYI.

You'll see something like this:

```
 ...
 2   3808773 (10)
 2   3809241 (10)  << still receiving points
 2   3809241 [0]   << boom! cap exceeded
 1   3809204 [15]  << cap exceeded, but still get points for accepts
 2   3809058 [0]
 2   3809204 [0]
 2   3809204 [0]
 2   3809159 [0]
 2   3682202 [0]
 1   3808636 [15]
 2   3808636 [0]
 2   3432741 [0]
 2   3808497 [0]
 1   3809241 [15]
-- 2010-09-28 rep +260  = 13997
```

Detailed [Reputation FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/133693)